# Global handler for model state errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We are creating MVC3 applications. We are using default editors and model state validation. We need to log application errors, but we prefer to make it by some kind of a global handler. We have a handler for unhandled exceptions, but we also want to log model state errors.

The question is: Where can we attach our logger to log such errors? Can we somehow override `ModelState` or detect situation when model served to view has model errors?

Comment: Maybe try checking out global filters as shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842721/asp-net-mvc-3-handleerror-global-filter-always-shows-iis-status-500-page

Comment: Thanks.. Thats nice.. could you put it as an answer, then I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global filters will most likely be your best way to go.
More from SO here: [asp.net mvc 3 handleerror global filter always shows IIS status 500 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842721/asp-net-mvc-3-handleerror-global-filter-always-shows-iis-status-500-page)

Or checkout the msdn doc here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Create a attribute to handle error and register it in the controller,

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
        {
           LogManager.GetLogger("somelogger").Error(exceptionContext.Exception.Message,exceptionContext.Exception);
            base.OnException(exceptionContext);
        }
    }
```

register it in the controller like this,

```
[EwmsErrorHandler(ExceptionType = typeof(base type of exception to handle), View = view to redirect)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
<controller code>
}
```

Comment: I know how to handle exceptions... the problem was to handle when model state is invalid...