# MVC3 HandleError not working with ASP.NET MVC3 EmptyTemplate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

In Visual Studio 2012 I created a new ASP.NET MVC3 Project using the **Empty** template. Then I created a `HomeController` with the following `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception("oops!");
    ViewBag.Message = "hello world";
    return View();
}
```

Next, I added a simple view for my HomeController:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

and inserted the following in the {root}/web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

Finally, I modified `/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` to look like:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    //Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
</h2>
```

When I run the project I get:

> 500 Internal Server Error. The website cannot display the page...

Then I decided to create another ASP.NET MVC3 Project using the **Internet** template. Inside the `HomeController` I throw an `Exception` exactly like I did above and I turned on `customErrors` again in the Web.config. When I run the project I get the correct results:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

What could I be missing between the two projects?

I've went line by line through the Web.config and didn't see any differences. The Global.asax file was untouched with both projects.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe this...

Thanks to Cosmin Onea comment below he had me inherit from `HandleErrorAttribute` and `OnException` was being fired as it should. After making that change I ran across this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845603/368593) and tested my page in Chrome where I see the appropriate message that has been there the whole time.

Although I'm still confused why one runs just fine in IE and the other application doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the HandleErrorAttribute as a global filter.

In your Global.asax, in the Application_Start event register the filter:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        ....
    }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

You can also apply the filter to a controller or an action directly. What the filter does, in case of an exception, it sets the Result on the filterContext to point to your Error view.

Comment: That's added when the project is created :(

Comment: are you running in IIS or IIS Express. I can't reproduce the problem, I always get the right result (the error view)

Comment: hmm. Both projects were originally running in IIS Express, but I tested them in IIS with the same results.

Comment: Create that inherits from the HandleError filter and override all the methods and in the debugger see if any gets called.